# How to convert Map[String,Seq[String]] to Map[String,String]

Tags: scala

I have a Map[String,Seq[String]] and want to basically covert it to a Map[String,String] since I know the sequence will only have one value.

Comment: The operation is called "map" (not to be confused with the Map ADT). What has been tried?

Comment: Looks like someone asked a very similar question back in january: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914954/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-seqstring-in-a-map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone else already mentioned `mapValues`, but if I were you I would do it like this:

```
scala> val m = Map(1 -> Seq(1), 2 -> Seq(2))
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(2))

scala> m.map { case (k,Seq(v)) => (k,v) }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
```

Two reasons:

1. The `mapValues` method produces a *view* of the result Map, meaning that the function will be recomputed *every time* you access an element.  Unless you plan on accessing each element exactly once, or you only plan on accessing a very small percentage of them, you don't want that recomputation to take place.
2. Using a case with `(k,Seq(v))` ensures that an exception will be thrown if the function ever sees a Seq that doesn't contain *exactly* one element.  Using `_(0)` or `_.head` will throw an exception if there are zero elements, but will not complain if you had more than one, which will likely result in mysterious bugs later on when things go missing without errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mapValues()`.

```
scala> Map("a" -> Seq("aaa"), "b" -> Seq("bbb"))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Seq[java.lang.String]] = M
ap(a -> List(aaa), b -> List(bbb))

scala> res0.mapValues(_(0))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(a
-> aaa, b -> bbb)
```

Comment: It's idiomatic to write `.head` instead of `(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it by doing the following:

```
mymap.flatMap(x => Map(x._1 -> x._2.head))
```

Comment: This is a start. Consider putting it *in the post* itself. However it can be done simpler and more efficiently with a normal `map` (or other specialized function).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another suggestion:

```
m mapValues { _.mkString }
```

This one's agnostic to whether the Seq has multiple elements -- it'll just concatenate all the  strings together. If you're concerned about the recomputation of each value, you can make it happen up-front:

```
(m mapValues { _.mkString }).view.force
```